# Where can i find Public Datasets related to Astronomy and other fields?

Tags: data-request, research, astronomy

I'm planning to do some research. Therefore, Appriciate if you could kindly help me to find out Astronomical datasets.

Comment: also see the [tag:astronomy] tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen in the news that Google released a brand new **[Google Dataset Search](https://toolbox.google.com/datasetsearch)** yesterday. It is a very convenient way to search for datasets, and overall it looks very promising.

Comment: @Kiritee we'll see after few comments.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://data.nasa.gov/.
They got plenty of freely available and even commercially usable datasets in a broad range of fields and topics.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, I have already gone through it and found out some valuable resources.

Answer (score 0):

You may find almost all the relevant astronomical catalogs at http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR